# PHP array database rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, rows

I have 4 tables within a database, each with the same field names. I want to display the current age of the pupil which I thought I could do through an array. The output I am looking for is 14 but I am currently getting the output of 11. The code I have is...

---

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM year8_records WHERE UPN = '$upn1'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$ageyears1 = $row['age_in_years']; // value is 11 in database


$query1 = "SELECT * FROM year9_records WHERE UPN = '$upn1'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1) or die("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

$ageyears2 = $row['age_in_years']; // value is 12 in database 


$query2 = "SELECT * FROM year10_records WHERE UPN = '$upn1'"; 
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

$ageyears3 = $row['age_in_years']; // value is 13 in database


$query3 = "SELECT * FROM year11_records WHERE UPN = '$upn1'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$query3) or die("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

$ageyears4 = $row['age_in_years']; // value is 14 in database



$result = array($ageyears1, $ageyears2, $ageyears3, $ageyears4);

echo "<b>Current Age</b></br>" . end($result) . " Years";
```

When I write..

```
$result = array("11","12","13","14");

echo "<b>Current Age</b></br>" . end($result) . " Years";
```

I get 14. 
But I really need it to be coming from the variable if possible....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy/Paste will get you every time. Just a few typos!

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM year8_records WHERE UPN = '$upn1'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$ageyears1 = $row['age_in_years']; // value is 11 in database


$query1 = "SELECT * FROM year9_records WHERE UPN = '$upn1'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1) or die("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

$ageyears2 = $row1['age_in_years']; // <-- changed


$query2 = "SELECT * FROM year10_records WHERE UPN = '$upn1'"; 
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

$ageyears3 = $row2['age_in_years']; // <-- changed

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM year11_records WHERE UPN = '$upn1'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$query3) or die("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

$ageyears4 = $row3['age_in_years']; // <-- changed



$result = array($ageyears1, $ageyears2, $ageyears3, $ageyears4);

echo "<b>Current Age</b></br>" . end($result) . " Years";
```

Comment: Something that seems so simple now that I didn't even spot, as problem solved!! Thanks a lot.